# Is there a word for a person who believes all events - past, present and future - have all been predetermined?

Tags: word-choice, epithet-requests

Such a person believes that whatever you did or do has been predetermined by a god or another omnipotent force. It's as if free will didn't exist.

e.g. "It's no use trying to discuss it with you. You are ..........

Comment: Seems almost like this might get more informed answers on the Philosophy Stack Exchange -- although it pretty clearly seems on topic here. Which part is more important, the "predetermined" or the "as if free will didn't exist" part? There are arguments that predetermination and free will are not incompatible.

Comment: ...a determinist?

Comment: @sumelic You caught me.  I can't see how predetermination and free will can coexist.

Comment: It may depend on if you mean something different by "predetermined/predeterminism" than ordinary "determinism." Wikipedia has a lot to say about it. But anyway, it's a pretty pedantic point; I only brought it up because it affects the connotation somewhat. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predeterminism

Comment: Someone was bound to ask this question...

Comment: Note that this is not necessarily bundled with a religious belief. There are many atheists who believe that there is no free will and everything is predetermined by physical and chemical reactions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A ***fatalist*** or a ***predestinarian***.

> *predestinarian*: A person who believes in predestination; a fatalist. Also in extended use. *[OED]*

From a philosophical standpoint:

> In philosophy, a fatalist is someone who holds specific beliefs about life, destiny, and the future. Fatalists share the certainty that fate has already been laid out in front of them, and that they have no real control over what will happen.
>
> *[vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/fatalist)*

You can also check:

- [Difference between ‘determinism’ and ‘fatalism’](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6927/difference-between-determinism-and-fatalism) - *philosophy.stackexchange.com*
- [Determinism vs. fatalism vs. predeterminism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatalism#Determinism_and_predeterminism) - *Wikipedia*

Comment: +1 for "fatalist," since that usually has the connotation sought for

Comment: Is there any difference in the context where "fatalist" and "predestinarian" are used?  Religion?

Comment: @Centaurus: They can be just same but they can diverge in philosophical and religious contexts. For example, predestination in Calvinism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_%28Calvinism%29

Comment: Note that "fatalist" is often used in a less rigorous sense to identify someone who feels that fate/the world/everything is against him, even though he may not believe that the future is predetermined.  Ie, a "pessimist", only more accepting/less resentful of his fate.

Comment: Never once heard *predestinarian*. Heard *fatalist* fifty million times. And not just in English. So you'll clearly be reaching a much bigger audience with the latter.

Comment: Was going to say fatalist.

Comment: @HotLicks Methinks it's incorrect to call someone a fatalist if they don't believe the future is predetermined, seeing as a fatalist is one who believes in fate which is by definition predetermined. Someone might throw their hands up and blame their misfortune on fate or the delusion of being beset by the rest of the world, but that doesn't make them a fatalist.

Comment: @talrnu - Whether incorrect or not, that's how the term is often used.

Comment: @talrnu - Think [Eeyore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eeyore).

Comment: @HotLicks Oh I agree, it's certainly the common usage. It's just worth noting the potential for inaccuracy and all that comes with, e.g. the offense of being mislabeled.

Comment: @talrnu - Not every word is defined as rigorously as you would seem to want.

Answer (score 4):

A [Calvinist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvinism#Predestination):

> Calvinism (also called the Reformed tradition, Reformed Christianity
>   or the Reformed faith) is a major branch of Protestantism that follows
>   the theological tradition and forms of Christian practice of John
>   Calvin and other Reformation-era theologians.
>
> ...
>
> **Predestination**:
>   Reformed theologians teach that sin so affects human nature that they
>   are unable even to exercise faith in Christ by their own will. While
>   people are said to retain will, in that they willfully sin, they are
>   unable to not sin because of the corruption of their nature due to
>   original sin.
>   To remedy this, Reformed Christians believe that God predestined some
>   people to be saved. This choice by God to save some is held to be
>   unconditional and not based on any characteristic or action on the
>   part of the person chosen.

Comment: A person can believe that all is predetermined and free will is an illusion without accepting the other tenets of Calvinism and, indeed, without being a Christian or believing in a God at all.

Comment: @DaveSherohman what would cause all things to occur without something that is uncaused  (god) forcing these actuations into actuality?

Comment: @hownowbrowncow That's more of a question of philosophy, but historically there was the concept in physics that all actions in a system are determined solely by the initial state of the system. With advances in our understanding of quantum mechanics that concept is now regarded as unlikely-to-impossible. Regardless, you don't need the concept of a deity to say that the universe is deterministic.

Comment: While @DaveSherohman is correct in his comment, I think this answer still is worth considering because Calvinism is a well-known branch of religion that espouses predestination. It is not unheard of for Calvinism to act as a conversational synonym for predestination without any implied reference to its other tenets.

Comment: @Daenyth So you give no evidence to support your statements and simple proceed with a 'regardless'.  Okay.  How could this initial pre-constructed  state form latter states?  It's logically nonsensical.  If this 'pre-constructed state' existed it would remain static without outside actuation.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow I can't explain physics to you over stack exchange comments. To take a simple analogy, you can predict the height of a ball over time if you begin with it raised in the air and then drop it. These predictions all come from the math used in physics and depend on various factors such as the force of gravitation, mass of the objects involved, etc. You seem to be suggesting that gravitation, magnetism, the speed of light, etc, are all constantly managed by an act of god, which I suppose it at least internally consistent but it's not required for physics to work.

Comment: @Daenyth You don't need to explain anything that I know quite a bit about. In order for your ball to ahieve it's position and then have the ability to do work (fall) it must exist at a state that has a non-minima potential energy.  This means that this energy must firs tbe put into the system and only THEN would it fall into an equilibria (at it's minima).  Linking back to the universe --the universal system would have to be initially created at a non-minima position in order for it to become actuated.  This is impossible as it implies that the system was acted upon.  Which is a contradiction.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow Your argument basically boils down to "the universe cannot exist without a Creator", which is _far_ outside the scope of this question or this site. Given that the universe does exist, and given an existing state of the universe, it is conceivable that all events could proceed deterministically from that point by solely physical/mechanical processes without requiring the influence of any deity or other outside actor. But, again, how the universe came into existence and achieved the given state is outside the scope of this discussion and site.

Answer (score 2):

A ***mechanist***

> *mechanist*: a person who believes in the doctrine of mechanism.

Specifically Anthropic Mechanism - via [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanism_(philosophy)#Anthropic_mechanism):

> The thesis in anthropic mechanism is not that everything can be
>   completely explained in mechanical terms (although some anthropic
>   mechanists may also believe that), but rather that *everything about
>   human beings can be completely explained in mechanical terms, as
>   surely as can everything about clockwork or gasoline engines.*

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this relates to predetermination? In my mind it's possible to perceive the human being mechanically and still believe in the power of human will over the state of the universe.

Comment: @talrnu I don't think I'm qualified to elaborate. I added the answer as it's a term I happen to know that wasn't mentioned already, I expected the answer would sit about exactly where it is in terms of up-votes :)

Answer (score 1):

*...It's as if free will didn't exist.*

Ermanen's post gives two great terms.

There's a stronger one that might apply:

**[Necessitarianist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessitarianism)**

> Necessitarianism is a metaphysical principle that **denies all mere possibility**; there is exactly one way for the world to be.
>
> It is the strongest member of a family of principles, including hard determinism, each of which **deny free will**, reasoning that **human actions are predetermined** by external or internal antecedents. **Necessitarianism is stronger than hard determinism**, because even the hard determinist would grant that the causal chain constituting the world might have been different as a whole, even though each member of that series could not have been different, given its antecedent causes.
>
> <sub>(From Wikipedia. Emphasis mine)</sub>